# Ipython Notebook (+ inline matplotlibplots) + shell + tmux

Tags: linux, terminal, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I think the process which is done with the [ipython notebook](http://ipython.org/notebook.html) is remarkable, especially for scientific calculations including plots, replacing more and more those commercial guis (like mathematica, matlab). 
But one thing what really bothers me is that while mainly working in the terminal via tmux, ipython, zsh and vim and it is impossible for me to connect these two worlds (ipython notebook and terminal).

Here comes my question / idea: What about a **ipython-notebook-like terminal**, combining all those nice features of my dotfiles with the nice features like inline plots and latexoutput of the notebook? I am imagining something which behaves like a general terminal but is somehow built differently, e.g. with hmtl5 rendering and so on.

Anyone knows if there is a project already tackling this?

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you already know about [ipython qtconsole](http://jupyter.org/qtconsole/stable/).  It's more like the ipython terminal prompt than a notebook, not really that great.

Here are a few options I think are closer to what you mean:

- `ipython console --existing` allows you from terminal to access the context of a browser notebook.
- https://github.com/nteract/jupyter-sidecar pops a graphing window from a regular terminal ipython:

  [image: jupyther-sidecar gif]
- https://github.com/millejoh/emacs-ipython-notebook/ (should be as simple as `M-x package-install RET ein RET` though didn't work for me).

  [image: elpy EIN gif]

  (In theory you could use it with one of Emacs' Vim emulations; no idea if that'd be appealing.)

Obviously none of these work purely in a text terminal but I think they could all work under SSH with X forwarding.

I'm just starting out trying these, will update when I have more to say...

Credits: most of these came from https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=9728143